# How to subtract x from every number in a listbox

Tags: c#, .net

So I have a list box of numbers and I want to subtract an integer from every single number of a list box. Here is an example:

```
1
2
3
4
5
```

I want to get the absolute value of the difference

```
Math.Abs(2 - 1)
Math.Abs(2 - 2)
Math.Abs(2 - 3)
Math.Abs(2 - 4)
Math.Abs(2 - 5)
```

And put them in a list box.
I've tried:

```
while (i < listBox1.Items.Count)
{
    result -= Convert.ToInt32(listBox1.Items[i++]);
    int result1 = Convert.ToInt32(result)
    int sub = Math.abs(result1)
}
```

Comment: Good. What have you tried and why doesn't work?

Comment: please read [ask] and take the [tour].  My guess is that a loop will be involved

Comment: `list.Select(n => x-n);` should do it. but show at least what you've tried

Comment: @M.kazemAkhgary That actually wouldn't work. He wants the absolute difference, not the difference

Comment: Is there a problem description or question anywhere in our future?  Please read [ask] and take the [tour]

Comment: @Plutonix I gave you my problem. It's in the body. I need this for class.

Comment: Yeah, please read [ask] and take the [tour]. `Questions seeking debugging help ("why isn't this code working?") must include the desired behavior, a specific problem or error and the shortest code necessary to reproduce it in the question itself. Questions without a clear problem statement are not useful to other readers.`  *I want...* is not a question or a problem

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Would this work :

I am using `Select(x => {return x;})` notation of linq to do an operation on the array element, and return a value. In this case, the operation is Math.abs of each element of the array and a given number. _absDiffs will be an `IEnumerable<int>`, which you could call `.ToArray()` on to turn it into `int[]`.

```
int[] _nums = {1,2,3,4,5};
int _number = 2;

var _absDiffs = _nums.Select(num=> { return Math.abs(_number - num);});
```

Comment: Yes, but I have parsed all of my numbers in the listbox, is there a way to change _nums to:
`listbox1.Items`
Never mind, I got it. Thanks!

Comment: Could you be a bit more clear what you mean by code? an example would help of the code that holds your numbers would be great.

Comment: Why are you using `Select(num => { return x; })` when you could just use `Select(num => x)`?

Comment: you could do that too, yes. I just find it easier to use the curly bracket whenever I'm manipulating a property in select statement. Easier to spot in the code. Just a personal preference.